# AFS not working after Upgrade to Debian 9

Tags: debian, gnome3, kerberos, kde5, afs

We are using Debian 8 and 9 with Gnome 3 / KDE 5, kerberos authentification and an AFS filesystem.

Debian 8 works fine, but after Upgrading some PCs to Debian 9 we have the following problem:

Gnome completly ignores the AFS-Tokens, this results in many errors when the user home is an AFS-directory (but login to gnome works). KDE cannot write some config after login, but starts. KDE programs (Dolphin and Konsole) have AFS-Rights, Gnome ones do not.

The KRB- and AFS-Tokens look fine:

```
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
28.11.2017 10:10:10  29.11.2017 11:10:10  krbtgt/xyz.com@XYZ.COM renew until 28.12.2017 10:10:10
28.11.2017 10:10:10  29.11.2017 11:10:10  afs/xyz.com@XYZ.COM renew until 28.12.2017 10:10:10
```

Special case: gnome-terminal:

```
user@pc: klist  #see foregoing results
user@pc: ls /afs/xyz.com/home/u/user
Permission denied

user@pc: aklog
user@pc: klist  #no difference
user@pc: ls /afs/xyz.com/home/u/user  #works!
[AFS Home Contents]
```

Other Applications do still not have permissions to view AFS-directories.

I am not really sure where to search for the problem. Maybe something related to pam? Any other ideas?

Comment: How the AFS FS is mounted?

Comment: @Paradox I installed openafs and its automatically mounted in /afs